# Jetty request.getSession(false) returning null, shouldn't be

Tags: jsp, servlets, jetty, session-cookies

My server is running java 8 and jetty 9.1.3.v20140225.

I have a straightforward servlet

```
@Override
public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
        ServletException {

    // get the parameters
    String contactIdParam = request.getParameter("contact_id");
    String authToken = request.getParameter("auth_token");

    // do things...

    // set session attributes
    logger.info("Setting session attributes");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("npoci", npoci);

    // move along
    final RequestDispatcher view = request
            .getRequestDispatcher("npo-portal.jsp");
    logger.info("time: " + session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

This takes me to my jsp.  The session timeout is 30 minutes.
The jsp successfully uses the session variables, calls request.getSession(false) as I have heard is necessary, and posts a form back to that servlet.  The first thing in the servlet's doPost is

```
    // Check session not null, and get interactions
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session == null) {
        logger.error("Session was null");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        return;
    }
```

Invariably, the session is null.  I have tried this in both Chrome and Firefox, and verified that the cookie is actually still present in my browser.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT

The servlet is now mapped to /npo-portal/update and does view.forward("npo-portal.jsp").  This has not fixed the problem.

Comment: based upon `.getRequestDispatcher("/npo-portal/npo-portal.jsp");` it may indicate that you are trying to use the same session in two different domains?

Comment: All on one domain, though I can't say for sure I'd know if it was otherwise.  But here, npo-portal.jsp is in the folder /npo-portal.

Comment: That is to say, all on one domain, I think?  npo-portal.jsp is in the folder /npo-portal, and the servlet is mapped in the web.xml to /schedule/update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the jsp - the form was posting to `http://localhost:8080/npo-portal/update`.  After changing the address of the post to just "update", the problem has been solved.  I am still a bit baffled as to why, but thanks to @ScaryWombat for getting me there.